# Need suggestions in Kentico 7 for Responsive Slides

Tags: kentico, responsive-slides

I am using Kentico 7 as the CMS to create the website. I am searching for a Rolling Banner web part, to put on the home page as the head banner, which can:

1. Be responsive.
2. Have caption area.
3. have navigation button on left and right.
4. would be nice to have instruction for me to insert to Kentico 7.
5. Must works in IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

I have tried to use Camera Slider but it does not work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

It's a pretty easy to implement slider that has good browser support, with good documentation, and can be responsive if you pass it the right arguments.

I typically place the wrapper for my rotators in the HTML Envelope of a repeater, then use build a transformation for my slides, like this:

```
<!--Envelope before-->
<div class="slick-wrapper">

  <!--Transformation-->
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{% GetImageMethod() %}">
  </div>

<!--Envelope after---->
</div>
```

However, keep in mind that IE 8 does not support media queries, so you'll want to use a JS feature detection library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)